# Edge detection for palm reader

Tags: c#, java, image-processing

I am totally strange to how the lines (heart line, fate line) of palm are detected so that I can access then to analyse. I am going to build a program that analyses palms and predicts accordingly.
It's totally edge detection but how can I find the separate lines? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up Canny's edge detector algorithm. It's arguably the best edge detector out there thus far.

Comment: I am so far suggested to find vertical and horizontal edges, but indeed where is the solution because the lines from the edges are neither completely vertical nor completely horizontal.

Comment: Canny's edge detector algorithm is capable of detecting edges regardless of whether they are horizontal/vertical. If you just want to detect horizontal/vertical edges you can run 2 filters across the image; the matrices are: [0, 1, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 1, 0] for vertical detection and [0, 0, 0; 1, 1, 1; 0, 0, 0] for horizontal edges. If it's more information about Canny's algorithm that you need, then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector is a good source or I'd recommend a book called "Digital Image Processing" by Gonzalez and Woods.

Comment: Be aware that these filters are to be used for grayscale images only, not colour. You should first convert the images to grayscale before operating on them.

Comment: canny for the best, i appreciate that. What would be my next possible step to find out the lines exactly (heart, fate) because edge detected image also include small patches too.

Comment: For the small patches you can configure the Canny algorithm - play around with the variables. As for the palm reading, that is your project so you must work that out yourself ;)